# Find the sum of the series in an infinite geometric progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series

In an infinite geometric progression, each term is equal to $3$ times the sum of the terms that
follow. If the first term of the series is $8$, find the sum of the series?

Could someone explain the first statement of the question. I would like to try the answer my own but I couldn't follow the question by itself. If someone can put it in numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) may help you.

Comment: I went through that similar notes i have. I am still figuring out how the gP is stream lined here.

Comment: The equations look like $a_1=8, a_2=3\displaystyle\sum_{r=3}^\infty a_r, a_3=3\displaystyle\sum_{r=4}^\infty a_r, … ,a_n=3\displaystyle\sum_{r=n+1}^\infty a_r, $. Try to proceed from here, maybe?

Comment: @insipidintegrator One more equation: $a_1=3\sum_{r=2}^\infty a_r.$ [since it says "each term... " which would include the first term.]

Comment: Yes @coffeemath I agree. It will help us actually find out what $a_2$ is by linking it with $a_1$, which we already know.  I overthought and excluded it.

Answer (score 0):

The series would be $$8, 8/3, 8/9,.....$$

The sum of the infinite series would be $$8/(1-(1/3))=8*(3/2)=12$$

Comment: Are you sure this sequence satisfies the description "each term is equal to 3 times *the sum of* the terms that follow"?